# How to remove a JTable column from both TableModel and TableColumnModel with setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel(false)?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

See at the end my SSCCE code. What I'm trying to achieve is:

- Equal number of columns in the data model and columns model
- Using `setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel(false)` to avoid recreation of columns model when a column is added or removed by the data/table model
- Ability to move columns

The large button adds a new column to the end. Each new column gets a unique identifier.

[image]

The header has a right click menu `HeaderMenu` to remove columns.  A timer calls `table.tableModel.addRow()` to insert a new row on the top. The data for each column is generated by class `Column`. In this demo the value is simply a rows counter with column's identifier.

[image]

In the actual table (not this demo)

- each column is a subclass of `Column` and generates meaningful data
- the menu also contains insert left/right and replace. This is achieved using similar as in the demo add/remove methods and by moving a column to the desired position
- the data model may contain a dozen of columns and over a million rows
- rows may be added with a time interval between a millisecond to several seconds, i.e. performance matters

This demo demonstrates the problem with deletion of columns which generates errors like this:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 >= 2
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:477)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:649)
at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2720)
at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5712)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCell(BasicTableUI.java:2114)
...
```

Please advise how to fix it. Here is the entire code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TableDemo extends JTable {

    private static class Column {

        private int rowsCounter = 0;
        private final String identifier;

        public Column(String identifier) {
            this.identifier = identifier;
        }

        private String nextCellValue() {
            return (rowsCounter++) + ", id: " + identifier;
        }
    }

    private static class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

        private final List<Column> columns = new ArrayList<>();
        private int nextColumnIdentifier = 0;

        private void addRow() {
            Object[] row = columns.stream().map(Column::nextCellValue).toArray();
            insertRow(0, row);
        }

        private TableColumn addColumn() {
            String identifier = String.valueOf(nextColumnIdentifier++);
            columns.add(new Column(identifier));
            addColumn(identifier);
            TableColumn tc = new TableColumn();
            tc.setIdentifier(identifier);
            tc.setHeaderValue(identifier);
            tc.setModelIndex(columns.size() - 1);
            return tc;
        }

        private void removeColumn(int idx) {
            columns.remove(idx);
            columnIdentifiers.remove(idx);
            for (Object row : dataVector) {
                ((Vector<?>) row).remove(idx);
            }
            fireTableStructureChanged();
        }
    }

    private static class HeaderMenu extends JPopupMenu {

        private int columnViewIndex;

        private HeaderMenu(final TableDemo table) {
            JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("Delete column");
            item.addActionListener(e -> table.deleteColumn(columnViewIndex));
            add(item);

            final MouseAdapter ma = new MouseAdapter() {

                boolean dragged = false;

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (!dragged && e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
                        final Point p = e.getPoint();
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                            columnViewIndex = table.columnAtPoint(p);
                            show(e.getComponent(), p.x, p.y);
                        });
                    }
                    dragged = false;
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    dragged = true;
                }
            };

            table.getTableHeader().addMouseListener(ma);
            table.getTableHeader().addMouseMotionListener(ma);
        }
    }

    private MyTableModel tableModel = new MyTableModel();

    private TableDemo() {
        new HeaderMenu(this);
        setModel(tableModel);
        setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel(false);
        setDefaultEditor(Object.class, null);
    }

    private void addColumn() {
        TableColumn tc = tableModel.addColumn();
        addColumn(tc);
    }

    void deleteColumn(int idxView) {
        TableColumn tc = getColumnModel().getColumn(idxView);
        tableModel.removeColumn(tc.getModelIndex());
        removeColumn(tc);
    }

    private static void buildAndShowGui() {
        TableDemo table = new TableDemo();
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(800, 300));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JScrollPane tableScrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        JButton buttonAdd = new JButton("Add column");
        buttonAdd.addActionListener(e -> table.addColumn());
        int gaps = 10;
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(gaps, gaps));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(gaps, gaps, gaps, gaps));
        panel.add(buttonAdd, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(tableScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(table.getClass().getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> table.tableModel.addRow());
            }
        }, 500, 100);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> buildAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: @TT., it does so. See `addColumn(identifier);` inside the `private TableColumn addColumn()`

Comment: Have run it now, can't point my finger at anything yet, what's interesting is that deleting the last column does not give the exception. Any other column does result in an exception.

Comment: @TT., right, and thank you for engaging. My colleague just found the problem and a solution. I will post it soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem is** that after removal of a column from some `modelIndex` in the table/data model, the `TableColumn#getModelIndex()` of some of the columns in the columns model may become shifted by 1. Here is an example, suppose the table has 3 columns and the code below produces `0 1 2`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < getColumnModel().getColumnCount(); i++) {
    System.out.print(getColumnModel().getColumn(i).getModelIndex() + " ");
}
```

Then after removal of the column `1` from both data model and column model, the output of this code becomes: `0 2`. Therefore `JTable` produces `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when accessing non-existing column `2` in the data model. This is why removal of the last column didn't generate an error.

**The solution is** to shift the `modelIndex` of the columns on the right side of the removed column. This can be done with a custom TableColumnModel:

```
private static class MyColumnsModel extends DefaultTableColumnModel {

    private TableColumn deleteColumn(int idxView) {
        if (selectionModel != null) {
            selectionModel.removeIndexInterval(idxView, idxView);
        }
        TableColumn tc = tableColumns.remove(idxView);
        tc.removePropertyChangeListener(this);
        for (TableColumn tableColumn : tableColumns) {
            if (tableColumn.getModelIndex() > tc.getModelIndex()) {
                tableColumn.setModelIndex(tableColumn.getModelIndex() - 1);
            }
        }
        return tc;
    }
}
```

And with add / remove methods of the table as following:

```
private void addColumn() {
    TableColumn tc = tableModel.addColumn();
    addColumn(tc); // equal to columnsModel.addColumn(tc);
}

private void deleteColumn(int idxView) {
    TableColumn tc = columnsModel.deleteColumn(idxView);
    tableModel.removeColumn(tc.getModelIndex());
}
```

Here is the entire fixed code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TableDemo extends JTable {

    private static class Column {

        private int rowsCounter = 0;
        private final String identifier;

        public Column(String identifier) {
            this.identifier = identifier;
        }

        private String nextCellValue() {
            return (rowsCounter++) + ", id: " + identifier;
        }
    }

    private static class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

        private final List<Column> columns = new ArrayList<>();
        private int nextColumnIdentifier = 0;

        private void addRow() {
            Object[] row = columns.stream().map(Column::nextCellValue).toArray();
            insertRow(0, row);
        }

        private TableColumn addColumn() {
            String identifier = String.valueOf(nextColumnIdentifier++);
            columns.add(new Column(identifier));
            addColumn(identifier);
            TableColumn tc = new TableColumn();
            tc.setIdentifier(identifier);
            tc.setHeaderValue(identifier);
            tc.setModelIndex(columns.size() - 1);
            return tc;
        }

        private void removeColumn(int idx) {
            columns.remove(idx);
            columnIdentifiers.remove(idx);
            for (Object row : dataVector) {
                ((Vector<?>) row).remove(idx);
            }
            fireTableStructureChanged();
        }
    }

    private static class MyColumnsModel extends DefaultTableColumnModel {

        private TableColumn deleteColumn(int idxView) {
            if (selectionModel != null) {
                selectionModel.removeIndexInterval(idxView, idxView);
            }
            TableColumn tc = tableColumns.remove(idxView);
            tc.removePropertyChangeListener(this);
            for (TableColumn tableColumn : tableColumns) {
                if (tableColumn.getModelIndex() > tc.getModelIndex()) {
                    tableColumn.setModelIndex(tableColumn.getModelIndex() - 1);
                }
            }
            return tc;
        }
    }

    private static class HeaderMenu extends JPopupMenu {

        private int columnViewIndex;

        private HeaderMenu(final TableDemo table) {
            JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("Delete column");
            item.addActionListener(e -> table.deleteColumn(columnViewIndex));
            add(item);

            final MouseAdapter ma = new MouseAdapter() {

                boolean dragged = false;

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (!dragged && e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
                        final Point p = e.getPoint();
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                            columnViewIndex = table.columnAtPoint(p);
                            show(e.getComponent(), p.x, p.y);
                        });
                    }
                    dragged = false;
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    dragged = true;
                }
            };

            table.getTableHeader().addMouseListener(ma);
            table.getTableHeader().addMouseMotionListener(ma);
        }
    }

    private MyTableModel tableModel = new MyTableModel();
    private MyColumnsModel columnsModel = new MyColumnsModel();

    private TableDemo() {
        new HeaderMenu(this);
        setModel(tableModel);
        setColumnModel(columnsModel);
        setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel(false);
        setDefaultEditor(Object.class, null);
    }

    private void addColumn() {
        TableColumn tc = tableModel.addColumn();
        addColumn(tc); // equal to columnsModel.addColumn(tc);
    }

    private void deleteColumn(int idxView) {
        TableColumn tc = columnsModel.deleteColumn(idxView);
        tableModel.removeColumn(tc.getModelIndex());
    }

    private static void buildAndShowGui() {
        TableDemo table = new TableDemo();
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(800, 300));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JScrollPane tableScrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        JButton buttonAdd = new JButton("Add column");
        buttonAdd.addActionListener(e -> table.addColumn());
        int gaps = 10;
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(gaps, gaps));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(gaps, gaps, gaps, gaps));
        panel.add(buttonAdd, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(tableScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(table.getClass().getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> table.tableModel.addRow());
            }
        }, 500, 100);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> buildAndShowGui());
    }
}
```